# How to update yum repositories to fetch newer versions of nodejs and related ones in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, centos7, yum, node.js, update

I'd like to update certain packages.

The latest versions are not presented.

```
$ sudo yum list nodejs
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos1.hti.pl
 * epel: ftp.uni-kl.de
 * extras: mirror.besthosting.ua
 * updates: centos1.hti.pl
Installed Packages
nodejs.x86_64        1:6.17.1-1.el7
```

NodeJS got 13th version already.

I need to update `nodejs` and `gcc*`.

OS: CentOS v7.6

Comment: Wait for maintainers to create rpm packages with new versions of software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put new versions of a package into a repository, unless it is managed by you (which is not the case, especially for the standard repos). Often the official repositories only include newer versions of a package very late, if ever. (For example for stability reasons)

But you can add other repositories to your system, so that yum can get the newer versions from there.

If you google for "nodejs 13 rpm repository" you can find the [distributions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) page of nodesource on github. When you look under "Enterprise Linux based distributions" you will find a command for adding the correct repository to your system (via curl). Then you can install the newer nodejs version from that repository.

```
# As root
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | bash -

# No root privileges 
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | sudo bash -
```

If the needed newer version of the `gcc` package is not already in that nodejs repo, you might have to find another repo, where the needed version is available.